# Missing Flow Button on Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, visual-workflow

So far I have a very simple visualforce page, because all I want it to be is a place to launch a particular *screen* flow:

```
<apex:page>
    <flow:interview name="Report_Issue" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/home/home.jsp')}" buttonLocation="top"/>
</apex:page>
```

The problem is that no button appears on the page for launching the flow.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that the page automatically opens right on the first screen of the flow, which is still blank (all I've done with the flow so far is add a blank screen).  So no button is necessary to get it going.